# SpamAssassin penalising DK Signed

Tags: email, mailchimp

I am checking an email for spam via isnotspam.com, in the results I'm receiving the following messages:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=production@studionec.com
Selector=
domain=
DomainKeys DNS Record=

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=production@studionec.com
Selector=mandrill
domain=mail2.wdc04.mandrillapp.com
DomainKeys DNS Record=mandrill._domainkey.mail2.wdc04.mandrillapp.com
```

In the SpamAssassin results it shows the following:

```
* 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, no
* trust
* [205.201.139.2 listed in list.dnswl.org]
* -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS SPF: HELO matches SPF record
* -0.0 T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD Envelope sender domain matches handover relay
* domain
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* 1.0 DK_SIGNED DK_SIGNED
* 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* 0.1 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
* 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
* valid
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
* 0.0 T_FILL_THIS_FORM_SHORT Fill in a short form with personal
* information
X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=4.8 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DK_SIGNED,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,
SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,T_FILL_THIS_FORM_SHORT,T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD autolearn=no
version=3.3.1
X-Spam-Score: 4.8
```

DK_SIGNED is presumably DomainKeys or DKIM, and it's giving a + 1.0 to the spam score, why is this happening and is there a way of stopping it?

I looked up DomainKeys and found the following listed in Wikipedia so is this a bug or poor configuration on my end?

> Both DomainKeys and DKIM were published in May 2007. DomainKeys was issued as a "historical" protocol and DKIM was issued as its standards-track replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DK_SIGNED rule comes from the [DomainKeys plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~jmason/Mail-SpamAssassin-3.2.5/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/DomainKeys.pm). It should have a corresponding DK_VERIFIED rule to check that the DomainKeys signature is valid, which would negate the score (if DK_VERIFIED == true) for a neutral result. The absence of the verification check indicates a configuration issue in SpamAssassin.

Note that the DomainKeys plugin is deprecated; its author states:

> THIS MODULE IS OFFICIALLY UNSUPPORTED.
>
> Please move on to DKIM like a responsible Internet user.  I have.
>
> I will leave this module here on CPAN for a while, just in case
>   someone   has grown to depend on it.  It is apparent that DK will not
>   be the way   of the future. Thus, it is time to put this module to
>   ground before it   causes any further harm.

The rules already include DKIM_SIGNED and DKIM_VALID, which are operating properly by adding to and then subtracting from the spam score, so it appears that the website's SA setup is incorrect.

Comment: To clarify, the SA setup is isnotspam.com and not the emails origin website? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the evidence is the presence of DK_SIGNED. I checked the source of both modules, and only DomainKeys has a header with that name.

Comment: Just realized what you were asking - by website's SA setup, I mean SpamAssassin on isnotspam.com.

Comment: That's great, thanks for your help. I'll have to find another test website.

Comment: You could try sending to check-auth@verifier.port25.com. This will reply with the details of basic SA processing. I tried it and they do use the DKIM module and not DomainKeys. See http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/ for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I can't Vote Up yet, but when I can I'll come back and upvote your answer too.